# Meterpreter detach command

Tags: exploit, http, metasploit, meterpreter

In a meterpreter reverse_https session when I use the detach command it closes my current session and then creates another, what it is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload will keep trying to connect back until `SessionExpirationTimeout` is hit. Default is one week.

Details [here](https://community.rapid7.com/community/metasploit/blog/2011/06/29/meterpreter-httphttps-communication).

> The payload has a hard-coded expiration date stamped into it during
>   the initial staging process. By default, this is one week from the
>   current date (relative to the target). This prevents a forgotten
>   session from connecting back indefinitely. You can control this
>   setting through the SessionExpirationTimeout advanced option.
>
> To avoid shutting down the payload but still exit the temporary
>   session, use the detach command from the Meterpreter prompt
>
> Setting [`SessionExpirationTimeout`] option to 0 and detaching the session will instruct the
>   payload to keep reaching out until the SessionCommunicationTimeout is
>   hit or the process is killed.